# Curl Write error when trying to write data read to a file

Tags: c, curl, libcurl, void-pointers, arrays

I'm executing the following curl call to read data from my website:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mysite.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(handle);
```

This is my callback method, write_data:

```
 size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t len, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
     const char* _file  = "file_path";
     FILE* _dataFile = fopen(_file, "a+");
     if (!_dataFile) {
         logMsg("Failed to open file to write to it");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     int num = fprintf(_dataFile, "%s", (char *) buffer);
     fclose(_dataFile);
     return num;
 }
```

I'm getting data in chunks and on gdb'ing I realized that in the last call, I'm getting 12303 bytes but writing 12310. It seems to me that the problem is in the way I'm writing content file, by casting the buffer to char.

So, my question is what is the best way to write data (to a file), read from Curl call without making extra copy? 
If I make a copy of the buffer received by malloc'ing a char array with `nmemb` bytes and append that to file, this method succeeds.

I'd also like to know if there is any other function to write formatted data to a file, which I can use in place of fprintf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of fprintf() in there is the cause. The buffer you get passed in to the callback from libcurl is *not* zero terminated so you can't assume that %s and fprintf() will do the right thing - even if it might in many cases by pure chance.

Use fwrite() or similar instead and tell it size of the buffer to output!